# Understanding groupby() function when sorting values

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to group my data using `groupby()` function to see the most expensive products in the whole dataset and the category the belong to. I would like to know if, for example, the most expensive products belong to category 'watches' or 'jewlery' or maybe in the first 10 most expensive there multiple categories. I was having trouble achieving it, and finally used:

```
df[['retail_price', 'product_category_tree']].groupby('retail_price').max().sort_values(by='retail_price', ascending=False)
```

The only thing is, though I used `max()` to make it possible to use `sort_values()` I'm not sure what exactly this `max()` does here. At first sight the result seems to produce what I expected but I would like to ask you if I'm right.

This is the result I get:

```
retail_price   product_category_tree
    
571230.0    ["Watches >> Wrist Watches >> Breitling Wrist ...
250500.0    ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
217500.0    ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
204600.0    ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
201000.0    ["Watches >> Wrist Watches >> Cartier Wrist Wa...
... ...
59.0        ["Toys & School Supplies >> School Supplies >>...
55.0        ["Pens & Stationery >> Office Supplies >> File...
49.0        ["Pens & Stationery >> School Supplies >> Penc...
36.0        ["Home Improvement >> Electricals >> Switches ...
35.0        ["Kitchen & Dining >> Housekeeping & Laundry >..
```

Does this result show me the most expensive products and their category? Or does this `max()` do something else here? If so, what can I use instead?

I would also appreciate any suggestion on how to change this function to also show one extra column `item_name`, but that's something that worries me less so it's not that important.

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it returns the max price of the whole dataset or the max price within given category.

Answer (score 1):

If you group by price, then max doesn't make much sense, because there is only one price per group. So I'm guessing that you want to get the most expensive item in each product category. If so, then you can use `groupby` and `rank` for this purpose

```
ranks = df.groupby('product_category_tree')['retail_price'].rank(method='dense', axis=1, ascending=False)

df = df.assign(grp_rank=ranks)

df.loc[df.grp_rank == 1, :]
```

Comment: I would like to see the most expensive items in general (from the whole dataset) and be able to inspect what category they belong to, for example to see which branches of the retail industry are for top-tier customers. I would like to see if the most expensive products belong to the same category, or maybe many different ones.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have been looking for a simple `sort_values()` function.
I sorted the dataset by the column of interest:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['retail_price'], ascending=False)
```

That gave me the following table:

```
       retail_price     product_category_tree
116     571230.0        ["Watches >> Wrist Watches >> Breitling Wrist ...
11631   250500.0        ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
11507   217500.0        ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
11464   204600.0        ["Furniture >> Living Room >> Sofas & Sectiona...
134     201000.0        ["Watches >> Wrist Watches >> Cartier Wrist Wa...
```